# Verbose output for apt-get

Tags: apt-get, ubuntu-16.04

A while ago `apt-get autoclean` printed to the console each package it was deleting with the size. Example:

```
Del gpm 1.19.6-11 [145kB]
```

It no longer prints these lines, but files still disappear from `/var/cache/apt/archives`. **How do I make apt-get always print these lines?**

I checked the man pages for `apt-get` and `apt-conf`. The simulate (`-s`) flag is not helpful because it does not list individual files.

I am now on Ubuntu 16.04 with apt 1.2.24